# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: tomcat, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

HTTPS access to our internal websites running Tomcat 6.0.32 on Java 1.6.0_21 stop working recently due to ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. these websites use self-signed certificates:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: aaa
Creation date: Oct 1, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=aa, OU=bb, O=cc, L=dd, ST=Ontario, C=CA
Issuer: CN=aa, OU=bb, O=cc, L=dd, ST=Ontario, C=CA
Serial number: 524b2c29
Valid from: Tue Oct 01 16:10:17 EDT 2013 until: Sun Jun 26 16:10:17 EDT 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  93:C4:69:A9:E2:0B:5A:3E:CE:08:E1:3C:1A:06:22:6A
         SHA1: 12:EA:64:29:F6:82:65:2C:0A:28:24:DA:35:B6:F1:29:1E:43:87:D9
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
         Version: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

I did a nmap scan on those servers and found that Tomcat has the follwoing cipher suites available:

```
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    8443/tcp open  https-alt
    | ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=<some_CN>    
    | Issuer: commonName=<some_CN>
    | Public Key type: dsa
    | Public Key bits: 1024
    | Not valid before: 2013-10-01T19:10:17+00:00
    | Not valid after:  2016-06-26T19:10:17+00:00
    | MD5:   93c4 69a9 e20b 5a3e ce08 e13c 1a06 226a
    |_SHA-1: 12ea 6429 f682 652c 0a28 24da 35b6 f129 1e43 87d9
    | ssl-enum-ciphers: 
    |   SSLv3: 
    |     ciphers: 
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - weak
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - weak
    |     compressors: 
    |       NULL
    |   TLSv1.0: 
    |     ciphers: 
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - weak
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
    |       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - weak
    |     compressors: 
    |       NULL
    |_  least strength: weak
```

Qualys SSL Client test shows my IE11 browser supports 26 cipher suites. One of them is:

```
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x32)   Forward Secrecy(see footnote)  128 

footnote: Cannot be used for Forward Secrecy because they require DSA keys, which are effectively limited to 1024 bits.
```

Does this cipher suite match "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong" on the Tomcat? I assume the Forward Secrecy footnote should not matter (it's not mandatory).

As for the protocols, my IE configuration supports SSL3.0 as well as TLS1.0,1.1,1.2.

It seems no justification for ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that (the generation of a new key pair / certificate) is required because you are currently using DSA public keys, which is shown by the line:

```
| Public Key type: dsa
```

Those cannot be used by RSA cipher suite, as that encrypts the session keys using RSA. RSA and DSA keys are not compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I just found one of the Tomcat ciphers:
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x32)
is in the list of  supported ciphers for IE11.
But IE11 is not able to establish a secure connection. Why?

Comment: Not sure about that. Note that the key size of you DSA key is rather small, that could have something to do with it. MS is also known to be finicky with regard to parameter support. Without log entries it is hard to tell though. RSA has drawbacks - it's not the most efficient algorithm - but it doesn't have parameter issues.

Comment: follwoing entry in the list from nmap scanning of the website: 
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong" 
and this entry from Qualys SSL Client Test of my IE11 browser: 
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x32)   Forward Secrecy(2)  128". footnote(2): Cannot be used for Forward Secrecy because they require DSA keys, which are effectively limited to 1024 bits. 

Do you think they match? I'm trying to avoid regenerating the keys.